# My 40_custom doesn't work

Tags: kali-linux, grub2, dual-boot

Hello and thanks for coming help me

My 40_custom is as follows :

```
#!/bin/sh
exec tail -n +3 $0



menuentry "Kali Linux custom configuration" {

    search --set=root --label Kali --hint hd0,gpt7
    configfile "(hd0,gpt7)/boot/grub/grub.cfg"
  }
```

And it does appear in `grep menuentry /boot/grub/grub.cfg` as `"Kali Linux custom configuration" {` without anything following the line.

My will is to boot on my Ubuntu Linux's grub but having a Kali boot option to the Kali's grub (therefore the use of 40_custom).

I've asked for help about it, but we were unable to find why it did fail. It has chmod 755 permissions, and it could not be the issue here. The partition might be correct, as I've got a SSD in /dev/nvme0n1/ and an HDD in /dev/sda/. The Kali is installed on my /dev/sda7/, and therefore it might be good.

So, to resume ; My 40_custom seems, for someone who assisted me, good, as they've tested it on their own, and it worked (changing partition directory, of course). My chmod might be good, unless I've missed something. I've updated the grub without seeing any entry called "Kali Linux custom configuration" afterward, and it is recognized as a menu entry, although it doesn't show on grub.

Some information : My boot.cfg and grub are both working fine, I have all my boot entries in order and working, except for the 40_custom file. What I meant by "without anything following the line" is that the "Kali Linux custom configuration" line is empty after the name, not that the whole menuentries are bad.

Thanks for your time and advices.

Comment: `grub-mkconfig` is a shell script. I would put debug prints into `grub-mkconfig` and/or `40_custom`. And I would get rid of superfluous empty lines in `40_custom`, just in case.

Comment: you mean, just adding the command to the file/terminal and see the output ?

Comment: I mean editing the scripts and adding `echo`s and `set -x` where appropriate. This is a weird problem, and requires weird approaches.

Comment: I've edited it, so the problem becomes clearer, I hope. What I understand from your answers is that you thought my whole boot.cfg was broken, which is not the case. Only the 40_custom doesn't work

Comment: If your `grub.cfg` contains a line with opening `{`, but no corresponding closing `}`, it **is** broken. `grub-mkconfig` compiles an incorrect `grub.cfg`, and my suggestions aim to help you figure out why and how.

Comment: Oh ok I get it
I'll do as you said